# Copying files over with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, go

I currently have a Go app using gRPC. I am attempting to write a Dockerfile that fetches all my deps and then builds my binary.

I am coming into issues where it can't find my proto files, they aren't added into Git so go mod download cant find the files. I've tried copying them into the service directory within Docker but it says they are out of the context of build.

My structure is

- serviceA - Dockerfile
- support/proto - proto files

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.13-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
        openssh-client \
        git \
        ca-certificates \
        make

RUN go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/RandomUser/*

# Enable Go Modules
ENV GO111MODULE=on

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

ARG ACCESS_TOKEN
ENV ACCESS_TOKEN=$ACCESS_TOKEN

RUN git config --global url."https://randomUser:${ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"

# Add go.mod and go.sum first to maximize caching
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Copy in the project
COPY . .

# Download all dependencies. Dependencies will be cached if the go.mod and go.sum files are not changed
RUN go mod download

# Build the Go app
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o company

EXPOSE 50010

ENTRYPOINT ["./company"]
```

In my go.mod I use

```
replace github.com/randomUser/support/proto/company => ./../support/proto/company
```

So my go app can find the files but this doesn't work when I run the docker container with docker-compose.

Has anyone come across something like this before?

Comment: It looks like you have to make the support/proto directory available during build time. For that, you have to build with a Docker context including that directory. Try building the image from the directory containing both directories.

Comment: The relative path of the `replace` is not working in your docker env. As @Burak Serdar noted, first ensure these files make it to the docker context - but then ensure they are in a directory that will match this same relative path.

Comment: This is an easy fix, if you don't mind have your `proto` directory in the same directory as your go source. If however you want the `go mod download` to create a reference to the proto directory - that will be more difficult.  Typically `replace` directives like this are for local development - they should be removed when doing builds against remote git versions.